# Get Sitecore item from Sitecore Commerce context

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am using Minion and i wanted to get the Sitecore item from  Minion? I can't add in the policy file. I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 version

Any pipeline or command to use here?

Comment: Hi, What item do you mean? If you want to retreive a Sitecore item from the commerce engine you can use the IGetItemByPathPipeline and IGetItemByIdPipeline pipelines

Comment: What will be the namespace to get this pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

**Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.IGetItemByIdPipeline**

```
string defaultLanguage = context.GetPolicy<GlobalEnvironmentPolicy>().DefaultLocale;
ItemModelArgument itemModelArgument = new ItemModelArgument("{itemPath}");
itemModelArgument.Language = defaultLanguage;
IEnumerable<ItemModel> itemModels = await _getItemsByPathPipeline.Run(itemModelArgument, context);
```

**Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.IGetItemsByPathPipeline**

```
string defaultLanguage = context.GetPolicy<GlobalEnvironmentPolicy>().DefaultLocale;
ItemModelArgument itemModelArgument = new ItemModelArgument("{ItemID}");
itemModelArgument.Language = defaultLanguage;
ItemModel itemModel = await _getItemByIdPipeline.Run(itemModelArgument, context);
```

Comment: SitecoreConnectionManager.GetItemById(context.CommerceContext, "{0A624A7F-B1BC-4923-974F-8EF02FB32D46}", "en");

Answer (score 0):

I am using commerce 9 update 3.
When i am using IGetItemByIdPipeline, it is returning only default 14 properties but when i use IGetItemByPathPipeline , i get the sitecore item field values also.

I need to get the sitecore fields, So i was able to get the sitecore item in  CalculateCartFulfillmentBlock pipeline by adding code shown below.

Make sure to have **CommerceCommander** __commander context injected into the pipeline block constructor.

```
ItemModelArgument itemModelArgument = new 
ItemModelArgument("/sitecore/Content/Data/DynamicShippingOptions");
itemModelArgument.Language = defaultLanguage;
ItemModel itemModel = await _commander.Pipeline<IGetItemByPathPipeline>().Run(itemModelArgument, context);
```